# How to change camera device with QZXing

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to utilize QZXing (https://github.com/ftylitak/qzxing) in a project for a client of mine. It seems to work okay for reading Qr codes, for my purposes. However, when moving it the client's device, which has two cameras, it defaulted to the back camera, which is not what I want (I hadn't realized there would be more than one camera).

I tried looking around QZXing's example projects, but there's no place to specify or change the camera as far as I could find in the qml. My project uses the qml almost exactly from the QZXing example (QZXingLive) project.

I looked online and found almost nothing useful. I found one thing that said I need to make my own QML object, but because of my little knowledge of it, I don't think that's possible at the moment.

I'd be interested in writing it in C++, if someone can point me in the right direction, where I could select the camera, that would be perfect. I'm not sure what classes make the QML objects even, so I need some guidance.

Does anyone know how to change the camera for QZXing?

Comment: This is too specific question,I think you should ask on Github.

Comment: Alright, I just asked on Github. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use another camera than the default one, you can set the `Camera`'s [`devideId` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#deviceId-prop). You can get all available device IDs from [`QtMultimedia.availableCameras`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-qtmultimedia.html#availableCameras-prop).

Here's an example from the doc:

```
Camera {
    id: camera
}

VideoOutput {
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: camera
}

ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: QtMultimedia.availableCameras
    delegate: Text {
        text: modelData.displayName

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: camera.deviceId = modelData.deviceId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I had no idea that even existed.